# How to split multi-page TIFF

Tags: python, image, opencv, tiff

I have a multi-page `TIFF` file and I want to split it to several png files. Normally, `imageMagick` and `graphicMagick` tools are used to deal with it. 
But error occurs. I already try to use many other codes like `PIL` but it does not work.

```
gm convert: JPEG compressed data indicates unexpected subsampling values. (OJPEGReadHeaderInfoSecStreamSof).
```

Comment: What error are you seeing if you try using ImageMagick's `convert` on the TIFF? That might provide us with a valuable clue.

Comment: Here is the imageMagick's error info : convert: Unknown field with tag 293 (0x125) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/995.
convert: ASCII value for tag "DocumentName" contains null byte in value; value incorrectly truncated during reading due to implementation limitations. `TIFFFetchNormalTag' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/995.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/995.

Answer (score 0):

If your TIFF is poorly formed and generally *"unhappy"*, you'll probably find that the tools that accompany `libtiff` are most permissive in their handling, so I would try:

```
tiffsplit document.tiff
```

Then use regular **ImageMagick** to convert the component parts to PNG individually.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I tried on my MAC by using tiffsplit to split TIFF but some components of original TIFF are unable to read which means broken already. But I used one online website split tool (http://www.zuohaotu.com/tiff-split.aspx it's a Chinese website) and it works.